# If I say First Monday or Second Monday of the Month what is the name for the First or Second Part?

Tags: terminology

Situation:  Someone says i want to meet the first monday of each month.  And i want to tell them that the first wouldn't work.  But i want to say it like:
Please choose a different xxxxx.

IE: if  i wanted to change the day i'd say. "Please choose a different day"

I'm thinking something close to frequency or ordinal..but i'm sure there's a term for it.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to say "Please choose a different day of the week" ?

Comment: 'Does it have to be the first Monday? Could it not be the second or third Monday?'

Answer (score 2):

Ask him to choose a different **week**.

Comment: May or may not be better than my answer as a DB label, but definitely better in most uses.

Comment: A database label would likely be named for its meaning or function rather than a general term...Meeting_Week_Number or some such.

Comment: Ugh, no, I definitely prefer just about everything here to that one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *ordinal* or *qualifier* to refer to that part of the sentence.

In practice though, you'd be more likely to be understood if you said "please choose a different Monday".

Comment: in actuality i need to name a label in a database...so i'm looking for a one or two word term.  Hoping it's been named at some point in human history

Comment: For that use I'd use *ordinal*, I just wouldn't use it in the UI of an application using said database, though I would in the object model of the application's code.